# What's the difference between inbound and outbound queues?

Tags: java, sql, queue

What's the difference between inbound and outbound queues , when to use one and not the other ?

Comment: Can you provide some background/context?

Comment: well, I want to know more about these queues, especially regarding db (sql) <=> java  communication (ex messaging).What means that a queue is inbound/outbound?